# How to run Twython on Python 2.7

Tags: twython

I'm trying to make a twitterbot like: ( http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-twitter-bot/)

I'm getting back from the script:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo python SillyTweeter.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "SillyTweeter.py", line 11,
>   in 
>       oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, NameError: name 'ACCESS_TOKEN' is not defined

When searching on this site, the answers are different things.  But I don't get why this is working for so many people, and not for me. I've tried: `pip install oauthlib` as was advised else on this site. But it did not help...

Please help me out! (I'm running Python 2.7)

The code:

```
{#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys  
from twython import Twython 

CONSUMER_KEY = 'FAiuNnj8bdY7XdbTEjLDLLXpL' 
CONSUMER_SECRET = '1reyhokR4LrIGbXNBL5l2xFyJQibnY5TfbQj7b98dlqi2Hn1eO'  
ACCESS_KEY = '3347749960-EgKjwTz4mzNND62n6okkaHIzvmDPgHa4T1JihPQ'  
ACCESS_SECRET ='24Jstmr1SPBJW1bMxLg7ARZ75uoQnYzUXvfGpEs5YFo0L'  
t = Twython(app_key=CONSUMER_KEY, app_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,          
oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, oauth_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

print t.getHomeTimeline() }
```

`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo pip install twython`

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twython in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages Requirement already satisfied
>   (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.1.0 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from twython) Requirement
>   already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests-oauthlib>=0.4.0
>   in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from twython) Requirement
>   already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauthlib>=0.6.2 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   requests-oauthlib>=0.4.0->twython)

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are defining `ACCESS_KEY` and `ACCESS_SECRET`, but you use `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` in the line it complains about. There are no variables in your code that are named `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET`, so I guess you meant to use mentioned `ACCESS_KEY` and `ACCESS_SECRET`.

Also, I hope the credentials in your code are just placeholders and not the real ones, since they really *shouldn't* be public. If they are, you should regenerate new ones in the Twitter development site to your app.